# Ember Data 1.0.0: what is expected format for belongsTo relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following models:

```
App.Publication = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  bodytext: DS.attr('string'),
  author: DS.belongsTo('author')
});

App.Author = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

And the folowing json data:

```
{
  "publications": [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'first title',
    bodytext: 'first body',
    author_id: 100
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'second title',
    bodytext: 'second post',
    author_id: 200
  }
];
}
```

In Ember Data RC12 this worked (you could specify author_id OR author in the json and the publication would always have the correct author linked).

In Ember Data 1.0.0 this no longer works; author is always null.

In some documents I found that - since I am using "author_id" in the json data (and not simply author) - I need to specify the key in the model; thus:

```
 author: DS.belongsTo('author', { key: 'author_id' })
```

This however does not work; the author in the publication remains null.

The only solution I see for now is to implement a custom serializer and override the author_id to author (via normailzeId); I cannot change my backend data structure ... thus:

```
App.MySerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  //Custom serializer used for all models
  normalizeId: function (hash) {
    hash.author = hash.author_id;
    delete hash.author_id;
    return hash;
  }
});
```

Is the above the correct way ?

Comment: You can still use the underscored properties, see my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ember Data 1.0 no longer does any payload normalization by default. The `key` configuration for `DS.belongsTo` has been removed as well so you will have to implement a custom serializer.

`normalizeId` is an internal serializer function used for converting primary keys to always be available at `id`. You shouldn't override this.

Instead, you can override the `keyForRelationship` method which is provided for this purpose.

You could use something like the following:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  keyForRelationship: function(rel, kind) {
    if (kind === 'belongsTo') {
      var underscored = rel.underscore();
      return underscored + "_id";
    } else {
      var singular = rel.singularize();
      var underscored = singular.underscore();
      return underscored + "_ids";
    }
  }
});
```

Note: I've also renamed the serializer to `App.ApplicationSerializer` so that it will be used as the default serializer for your application.

Finally, if you haven't already found it, please take a look at the transition notes here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

If you read through the transition document shortly after the initial 1.0.0.beta.1 release I would recommend taking a look again as there have been a number of additions, particularly regarding serialization.

Comment: Thx Justin.  keyForRelationship looks something very new.  I am confused with your sample: you add "_id" to the relationship, whereas my findings indicate that I need to remove the _id from the relationship property.  A sample is given in the transition note and in this sample they also remove _id.  Am I missing something ?

Comment: There are a few different normalization hooks available. The example in [TRANSITION.md](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md) implements `normalize` and munges the payload keys the way you would expect. However, implementing `keyForRelationship` as above has the same effect. The reason is that within the default implementation of `normalize`, `normalizeRelationships` is called which iterates over each relationship defined on the model, uses `keyForRelationship` to find each relationship attribute in the payload, and finally sets the expected model attribute using it.

Comment: If you are interested, the source is here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/4bf1b7a09575ae65e1570a4a4c12c629bdd86a5e/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest_serializer.js#L205-L221

Comment: Thanks for this, been trying to get my head around relationship handling in the beta for a while.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Ember 1.0.0 Transition Guide](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#underscored-keys-_id-and-_ids):

**Underscored Keys, `_id` and `_ids`**

In 0.13, the REST Adapter automatically camelized incoming keys for you. It also expected belongsTo relationships to be listed under `name_id` and `hasMany` relationships to be listed under `name_ids`.

If your application returns json with underscored attributes and `_id` or `_ids` for relation, you can extend `ActiveModelSerializer` and all will work out of the box.

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({});
```

**Note**: DS.ActiveModelSerializer is not to be confused with the ActiveModelSerializer gem that is part of Rails API project. A conventional Rails API project with produce underscored output and the DS.ActiveModelSerializer will perform the expected normalization behavior such as camelizing property keys in your JSON.